# What is the best backend for a jquery mobile web app?

Tags: database, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, backend

i want to know what is the best backend (database) for a jquery mobile web app and if you have any tutorials and tips that i could use? What is the best database to support a jquery mobile web app?

Thanks

Comment: What you mean by backend??? You can use any Language you know, PHP, java

Comment: database behind the jquery mobile web app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backends for mobile apps is a completely different concept altogether when it comes to the context of market. There's a new revolution of [`mBaaS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backend_as_a_service) providers - mobile Backend as a Service. Instead of having your own backend, writing your own web services and exposing them to your app, I would suggest trying a mBaaS, unless the situation is demanding to go by the traditional ways.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'm trying to build an app for a small fictional business but only using jquery mobile so that is why i wanted to know what database is best for such an app. (its for a project)

Comment: Even for a project you can use mBaaS. Certain providers, say Parse.com , provide a huge number of free hits even on trial accounts.